# CSS transform scale cut off the image

Tags: css

I have an image inside the container which has overflow scroll, I am going to implement the zooming feature, so for zoom in I want to scale up the image. In the snippet given below, there are two images, first has scale value 1, and you can see the whole image by scroll vertically and horizontally. But when its scale value is 2, I cant be able to see the whole image by scrolling along x or y direction. It seems like scaling up the image make cut off an image. What is the solution to overcome this problem.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

img {
  transform: scale(1)
}

.div2 {
margin-top: 5px;
}

.div2 img {
 transform: scale(2)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <img src="https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: scale is only a visual effect, it won't make the scroll bigger

Comment: The scaling is doing exactly as it should - your second image is zoomed in twice as much as the first. It's not doing anything to the size of the div, because you've given it a fixed height and width

Answer (score 1):

`Transform: scale(2)` can't define the value of img's width/height for `.div2`

But you can use `jquery` to scale.

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    div {
      height: 200px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    img {
      transform: scale(1)
    }

    .div2 {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
        <img src="https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    var originImgWidth = $('.div2 > img').width();
    var originImgHeight = $('.div2 > img').height();
    var ratio = 2;

    //Check img orgin size
    //console.log('originSize:', originImgWidth, originImgHeight);

    $('.div2 > img').css({
        'width': originImgWidth * ratio + 'px',
        'height': originImgHeight * ratio + 'px'
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this will help. Here are two examples, using scale and transition. The `transform-origin` will change how the picture zooms.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
    
.div2 img {
  background-image: url(https://www.tennisworldusa.org/imgb/57551/roger-federer-to-take-a-threemonth-break-i-won-t-play-roland-garros-.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.div2 img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <img>
</div>
```